# How to create a list with column name for each row of a df

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

i have this df:

[have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZEYQ.png)

and i want to make a list with the column name and data for each row who looks like this:

[{'userid': '1', 'account_holder': 'Vince', 'broker': '1090', 'account_id': '807521'},
{'userid': '2', 'account_holder': 'Joana', 'broker': '3055', 'account_id': '272167'},
{'userid': '3', 'account_holder': 'Dominique', 'broker': '5143', 'account_id': '37009'},
{'userid': '4', 'account_holder': 'James', 'broker': '5522', 'account_id': '905527'}]

can you help me?

i'm new at python and searched for info but not finding anything about it

Comment: If I understand the question, you could transpose the original dataframe and convert to dict `df.T.to_dict()`. Give it a try and if that's what you meant, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use your expected output to create a dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'userid': '1', 'account_holder': 'Vince', 'broker': '1090', 'account_id': '807521'}, {'userid': '2', 'account_holder': 'Joana', 'broker': '3055', 'account_id': '272167'}, {'userid': '3', 'account_holder': 'Dominique', 'broker': '5143', 'account_id': '37009'}, {'userid': '4', 'account_holder': 'James', 'broker': '5522', 'account_id': '905527'}])
>>> df
  userid account_holder broker account_id
0      1          Vince   1090     807521
1      2          Joana   3055     272167
2      3      Dominique   5143      37009
3      4          James   5522     905527
```

DataFrame has a `to_dict` method that can output in multiple ways. `help(pd.DataFrame.to_dict)` says

```
orient : str {'dict', 'list', 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index'}
    Determines the type of the values of the dictionary.

    - 'dict' (default) : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
    - 'list' : dict like {column -> [values]}
    - 'series' : dict like {column -> Series(values)}
    - 'split' : dict like
      {'index' -> [index], 'columns' -> [columns], 'data' -> [values]}
    - 'records' : list like
      [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]
    - 'index' : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
```

You can call `to_dict` with "records" orientation to get the result you want

```
>>> df.to_dict("records")
[{'userid': '1', 'account_holder': 'Vince', 'broker': '1090', 'account_id': '807521'}, {'userid': '2', 'account_holder': 'Joana', 'broker': '3055', 'account_id': '272167'}, {'userid': '3', 'account_holder': 'Dominique', 'broker': '5143', 'account_id': '37009'}, {'userid': '4', 'account_holder': 'James', 'broker': '5522', 'account_id': '905527'}]
```

Comment: it worked! didnt know that i could use this parameters